# Read data from BLOB URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, download, blob

I have a BLOB URL, and I want to recreate it as a second BLOB URL, so that it is downloaded by default.

```js
var blob1 = new Blob(["Hello world!"], { type: "text/plain" });
url1 = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob1);

blob2=new Blob([url1], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
url2 = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob2);

var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = url2;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

See in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7spry3jn/

But this only creates a text file containint the first URL. How can I Read data from the first BLOB URL in Javascript and feed it to create the second BLOB?

Comment: Why you want to create a 2nd blob?

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen The first one doesn't force download. So I have to create a second one with such feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `download` attr in `anchor` element, that force the download and you dont need to reate another blob.

> But you need to pay attentio about browser support, see here all the browsers that accept the `download`attr: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=download)

```js
var blob1 = new Blob(["Hello world!"], { type: "text/plain" });
url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob1);

var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = url;
a.setAttribute("download","Any name");
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

And to read the content from a `Blob` you can use `FileReader` like this:

```js
var myBlob = new Blob(["Hello"], {type : "text/plain"});
var myReader = new FileReader();
//handler executed once reading(blob content referenced to a variable) from blob is finished. 
myReader.addEventListener("loadend", function(e){
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = e.srcElement.result;//prints a string
});
//start the reading process.
myReader.readAsText(myBlob);
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox. I don't know why. Btw, I'm doing this to download several BLOB urls. Is there a better way to to do this job?

Comment: I don't know why html5 download doens't work in Firefox for me. But, thanks. Anyway, your solution saved my day!