# Get data from blob URL in src attribute of img element

Tags: javascript, html, blob, fileapi

Let's say I have the following `img` element in a page that has been created by some unknown Javascript:

```
<img src="blob:https://examplesite.com/path-to-blob">
```

can I use the `src` attribute to download the file associated with this `img` tag?

I found [Read data from BLOB URL in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670381/read-data-from-blob-url-in-javascript), but that question is in a different context.

I tried `fetch("blob:https://examplesite.com/path-to-blob")` in the Chrome DevTools, but I got `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Is there anything I can do to access the data associated with this `img` tag?

Comment: Removing the `blob` prefix and using `fetch("https://drive.google.com/a6a5ddda-3d77-4065-a59f-acddd1cdb3b7")` gives a 404 error. Accessing the URL directly also gives the same "Not Found Error 404" error, which makes sense, because from my reading a blob URL is not a real URL.

Comment: Deleted my previous comments, I had forgotten about the format returned by `createObjectURL()`

Comment: _blob_ URLs like that must be created by `URL.createObjectURL()` and are only valid for the lifetime of the `document` that created them (or until `revokeObjectURL()` is called). Where **exactly** does this URL come from?

Comment: @Roymunson Hello, did you find a solution?